# Race Condition in a Online Coupon Generating Application

Tags: web-applications, race-condition

Suppose I have an application in which a user has to enter a scratch card code and it transfers $1000 to his account!

Now my application would be listening for codes. Something like this would happen-

```
def RedeemCode(code, user_id):
    isvalid = checkValidCode(code) # queries database
    if isvalid is True:
        setCodeAsExpired(code) # updates database
        addMoneyToAccount(amount=1000, id=user_id)
```

Suppose 2 requests come in with the same `code` and `user_id` at exactly same time. Also suppose that `checkValidCode` returns `True` for both of them as the order of execution is:

`checkValidCode[request1] -> checkValidCode[request2] -> setCodeAsExpired[request1] -> setCodeAsExpired[request2]`

With this approach the issue of money getting credited twice exists.

How is the system designed in such cases to prevent such issues? 
(Sorry if this is a trivial problem. I was thinking about how this system would work and was stuck at this point)

Comment: Use locks... if the programming language supports multithreading there should be a possibility to put locks on objects or methods. You can also add locks to the database as well to prevent the same value being updated twice.

Comment: @Darwind So how would lock on methods work out? Would it lock a method or a method and args combination? How will DB lock work? Generally isn't it a case where you put a lock on while you are writing so that others cant write or maybe others cant read also.

Comment: When you lock a method or object other callers are told to wait until it's their turn. If locking a method the first caller will have to leave the method before anyone else can start to run the method for instance. There are different ways to do database locking. Some use optimistic concurrency control and some use pessimistic concurrency control. There are probably other ways to handle concurrency. You're asking a very "abstract" question, so you get an abstract answer ;-) Look up the terms I've written and you'll probably get wiser :-) "concurrency and locking" is probably the keywords here.

Comment: I guess the locking of method wont work if I have say a thousand requests in a second. Yea it is abstract and freshly cooked :)

Comment: Well the 1000 requests will probably just be put to sleep until it's their turn. I think that's very language dependent how many requests can be put into a queue for instance. If you're talking about web requests you'd probably use something like a message queue to store all requests and then fire them in the order they came into the queue. But in general I don't think there's any specific limit for how many threads/requests that can wait for a method to return.

Comment: @Darwind surely I would be having queues. But they would be having some max lengths either set by the implementation or system resources and would run over at some point of time.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77242/discussion-between-hyades-and-darwind).

Answer (score 1):

This is where you want locks and a transactional design (atomic). You want the process of checking validity, expiring the code, and crediting the user to be a single atomic, indivisible transaction.

However you create this locked, indivisible transaction varies between languages/libraries/frameworks.

Since the code you showed is in Python, it may not even possible to execute it concurrently (see Python's Global Interpreter Lock).

In Java you have a `synchronized` keyword on methods which locks the entire object, so not only does it prevent any other threads from executing that specific method's code simultaneously, but also it'll lock them out of calling any other synchronized methods in the same object.

In C#, you manage your own locks on resources, but don't require a separate lock-specific object type. There's language-level support with a `lock` keyword, but it's a bit more granular than the Java design. This is both good and bad: it can be good for efficiency to be able to lock things with a bit more discretion, but it can be bad for security and more human error-prone.

In more *"roll up your sleeves and get dirty"* hardware-level languages like C and C++, you're often dealing with critical sections as separate object types to lock appropriate sections of code based on the level of granularity you choose rather than just whole objects. In those cases, one might even get down to the level of compare and swap (CAS) interlocked atomic operations to ensure that even something like incrementing an integer is an atomic transaction (it actually isn't necessarily atomic at the hardware level, and two threads trying to increment the same integer can actually result in a race condition).

Note that locks can be very expensive and, in worst-case scenarios, effectively turn your system's performance into that which is worst than single-threaded due to the number of threads being suspended while waiting for access to a shared resource that is highly contended. It can create thread traffic jams where they're bottlenecked and waiting for their turn.

So there are a lot of strategies to optimize this, including lock-free designs (and sometimes even wait-free). There are also sometimes way to split apart a shared resource.

For example, your customer database might be split apart into separate chunks that only require a lock if two requests from the same customer come in. This way you turn one potentially massive shared resource into many resources that can be locked separately.

You seemed to be wondering if locks could time out. Some designs allow it, but if they do, they always time out towards the side of omitting execution of the critical section (basically erring towards the side of aborting the attempt). It would ruin the whole point of locking if a thread could time out towards the side of concurrently executing the critical section. So you have a strong guarantee when you put a lock around something that no two threads will execute that code simultaneously.

What you want to research is thread locks, how they work, and the general mentality of transactional coding and thinking. This is also important for exception and error handling to make sure that if you encounter an error in the middle of a critical operation, that it doesn't leave the system in a 'half-completed' invalid state. Transactions should succeed as a whole or abort/rollback as a whole.

Answer (score 0):

When the database is the source of truth for your application, enforcing data integrity at the database level with constraints is important. As I’ve shown, there are situations where validations will pass even though the end result once persisted is invalid. In the worst case situations, this is a serious security flaw and even in the best case situations, it will lead to data integrity issues. The easy solution is to add a unique index on the combination of the model’s foreign key plus the coupon code field so that the database server will reject duplicates itself since modern database servers are both atomic and thread-safe.